# How to stop navigation bar from blocking page

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, navigation

Last week I wrote to ask about a navigation bar I was creating. Only just began FCC and I'm very new.

**Problem:**Navigate bar seems to be blocking content and in the way of other elements. Notice how "this is text" is blocked. Even after tons of copying.

I was able to finally get a basic navigation bar working with the highlight function working. However, the bar is now blocking text it seems. I want to have the navigation bar simply sit on top of the screen and scroll down with the user as they scroll so that they can click any of the buttons whenever they please.

I have only completed HTML, CSS, jQuery, and Bootstrap on FCC. These were extremely basic lessons.

https://codepen.io/bomaran/pen/EvoRpR

Here is the code: 
**CSS**:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  /*----Fixes Nav Bar to top---*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
 width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*--Drop down buttons--*/
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  /*how does right:0; keep text from going off screen?*/
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4CAF50}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!----Nav Bar ---->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown" style="float:right"><a href="#About" 
class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">日本生活</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
<!---End Nav Bar---->
</div>
<!---background images --->

<p> this is text this is text this is text this is text v v this is text v v 
this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is 
textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is 
textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is 
textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is text 
</p>
```

**Goal:**Navigation bar needs to remain in place as the user scrolls; so user is able to use the navigation bar at any point during their time on the site. The goal is like this (https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/YqLyXB)

I do believe this example page might be using more than HTML, CSS, jquery, and bootstrap. However I am new to coding and have no idea what I am doing. Goal is to only use languages I know now.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS style:

```css
.navbar {
position: fixed; 
z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    //your code navbar
</div>
```

Comment: The problem still exists it seems

Comment: z-index is not required. Use it only if there are problems with the display of the block, namely it is on the layer below the other elements. z-index fixes this problem and makes the layer above all elements.

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the fact that my navigation bar is a UL. But I'm not sure otherwise why its still not working. I added both bits of code

Comment: Add the height of the navigation block.

Comment: There is used a fixed point position. If the content is not visible, then you need to give the block with the content an indent, for example, through the margin-top style.

Comment: @bomaran and xtremeal29: In addition to make the navigation fixed, one also need to add a padding to the border, matching the height of the navigation, plus any additional space one want between the navigation's bottom and the page's content: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLJxjp